# How to create index for NOT IN on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing

```
select *
from expenses
where state not IN ('DELETED','SUCCESS')
```

I have two index.

```
CREATE INDEX testttt  ON expenses (state);
CREATE INDEX testttt2 ON expenses USING GIN(state);
```

But not handle above query.

```
Seq Scan on expenses  (cost=0.00..633.45 rows=15955 width=2140) (actual time=0.961..10.210 rows=16116 loops=1)
"  Filter: ((state)::text <> ALL ('{DELETED,SUCCESS}'::text[]))"
  Buffers: shared read=432
Planning Time: 0.139 ms
Execution Time: 12.114 ms
```

Comment: Please post the table definition of `expenses`, what is the type of the `state` column? How many rows are in that table? Can you show the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` please?

Comment: Please add the query plan.

Comment: 16.000 rows in 12 milliseconds, what kind of runtime do you expect for this amount of records?

Comment: I want that my query handle an INDEX

Comment: "I want" and its companion "I don't want" are often the worst phrases in development. Concentrate on what you *need*. Do you need a retrieval rate greater than 1.3M/sec. If so the how can you get it. If not move on to parts of the system/app that need your attention. Do not spend your costly and limited time where it is not needed.  Also keep in mind that *sometimes a sequential scan is by far the most efficient.*

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the filter removed no rows, so you are reading the complete table.  For that, a sequential scan is more efficient than an index scan, so PostgreSQL prefers it.